# UITableViewCell is not showing Label

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

Anybody knows whats wrong here ? I am trying to  add a tableView Inside my ParentView's subView , `UITableView` is there (I can scroll it but Cells are not showing the label text)... my code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

let containeView = UIView()
var tableView = UITableView()

let mArray = ["HELLO","FROM","THE","OTHER","SIDE"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    containeView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, self.view.frame.size.height - 40)
    tableView = UITableView(frame: containeView.bounds, style: .Plain)
    containeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    containeView.center = self.view.center
    containeView.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableView.reloadData()


    view.addSubview(containeView)

    tableView.reloadData()
 }


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell

        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        cell?.textLabel?.text = mArray[indexPath.row]
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        print("CELL")


    return cell!
}
}
```

I tried to set the color of textLabel's text also tried to set the background color of cell but nothing worked for me

---

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**
Needed to add the state for Label (Label is appearing when i'm selecting the cell)

Can anyone explain me what is actually happening here , i can't select row 1 , and when i'm selecting my row it turns to Gray and when i select any other row previous selected row turns to blue and when i scroll and cell disappear from the screen (offset) they again become invisible until i select any row , any clue ??

[image]

Comment: `print("CELL")` printing in console or not?

Comment: Why do you dequeue the cell if it's for alloc/init it just after?

Comment: print cell is printing fine @BhavinRamani

Comment: i dont know i tried so many time in different  pattern thought it'll work ,  its not correct ? @Larme

Comment: got it working guys , needed to add the state for Label (Label is appearing when i'm selecting the cell)

Answer (score 2):

Try modify your code to this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = mArray[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    print("CELL")

    return cell!
}
```